# Proving $(A \oplus B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \oplus(B\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm trying to understand a proof that: $$(A \oplus B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \oplus(B\cap C)$$

So in the example, someone starts the proof from:
$$(A \cap C) \oplus(B\cap C)$$

and after a few steps got to the following:
$$((A \land C)\lor (B \land C )) \land (( \lnot A \lor \lnot C) \lor (\lnot B \lor \lnot C))$$
and then simplified it to:

$$((A\lor B) \land C)\land((\lnot A\lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C)) $$

I can see that to get from $$( \lnot A \lor \lnot C) \lor (\lnot B \lor \lnot C)$$ to $$(\lnot A\lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C)$$ the  associative law and idempotent law has been applied to simplify.

However I can't figure out how to get from: $$(A \land C)\lor (B \land C )$$ to $$(A\lor B) \land C)$$

Many thanks!

Comment: So basically, you need explanation on why $( A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$ ?  You can refer to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697305/prove-a-cup-b-cap-c-a-cap-c-cup-b-cap-c

Comment: I should have been more precise. Thanks!

Comment: @Jak Yes. By $\oplus$, did you mean the disjoint union (partially defined) ? In fact, when $\oplus$ is for the direct sum of vector subspaces (which is common), this is not true (take $A,B,C$ distinct lines in the plane).

Comment: Sorry, for ⊕ I meant to describe symmetric difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is distributive law, check this list of [Logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#General_logical_equivalences[4]) might be helpful
$${\displaystyle (\color{blue}q\wedge\color{red}p)\vee (\color{green}r\wedge\color{red}p)}\equiv (\color{blue}q\vee \color{green}r)\wedge\color{red}p\tag*{distributive law}$$
Hence $(\color{blue}A∧\color{red}C)∨(\color{green}B∧\color{red}C)\equiv(\color{blue}A∨\color{green}B)∧\color{red}C$ hold.