# Sets; is (A∩B)∪C the same as A∩(B∪C)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have this homework question, asking to prove (A∩B)∪C= (A∪C)∩(B∪C) , but that doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't it be A∩(B∪C)= (A∪C)∩(B∪C) ?
When I check in the professors notes, that's also what it says, but I'm not sure (I'm very new to maths).
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Try your idea out with $A$ being the set of all animals, $B$ being the set of all bears and $C$ being the set of all chairs. If you are right then chairs are all animals.

Comment: Are you familiar with propositional logic, e.g., "element chasing"?  If you know set identities, then you are dealing with the distributive property, in both cases.

Comment: Draw Venn diagram to convince yourself.

Comment: In problems like these it's always instructive to take one set to be the empty set. What happens when $A=\emptyset$?

Comment: Draw a ven diagram.  But not $A\cap (whatever)$ is entirely contained in $A$.  But $(whatever)\cup C$ is a set that entirely contains $C$.  So if they were equal then $C$ would have to be entirely contained in $A$ and there's no reason at all that should be true.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not! There are a lot of small cases which would make this claim false, such as the suggestion by Randy Marsh:

$$ A = \emptyset, C = \{ \text{Your Choice} \}$$
And knowing these facts $$ A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \\ A \cup \emptyset = A$$

You would get that:

$$ ( \emptyset \cap B) \cup C = \emptyset \cup C = C \\ \text{While:} \\ A \cap (B \cup C) = \emptyset \cap (B \cup C) = \emptyset $$

And those are really different...
Here is a link that might help: [Prove $ (A \cup B) \cap C$ = $(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697305/prove-a-cup-b-cap-c-a-cap-c-cup-b-cap-c)

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah I'm pretty sure it's a typo in the paper, but I suddently wasn't sure, so thank you for your answer!