# Prove that for every three sets A, B, and C we have (A ∪ B) ∩ C = (A ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ C).

Tags: proof-explanation

I need help solving this question. I understand that we need to prove that the LHS is a subset of the RHS and that the RHS is a subset of the LHS, but I don't really know what to do afterwards.

Comment: You might want to include your attempts so that this doesn't become a "solve my homework" kind of question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $ (A \cup B) \cap C$ = $(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697305/prove-a-cup-b-cap-c-a-cap-c-cup-b-cap-c)

Comment: @A.Goodier Nope. Sorry, but it does it in another way rather than the way I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: @DiegoCimadom Yeah. You're probably right. However, I'm still a beginner when it comes to proofs, so I'd like to just understand how to write the solution first.

Comment: @CodingKook Also see the linked questions on that post. This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take an arbitrary element $x \in (A \cup B) \cap C.$ This is the same as saying that $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in C.$ Using the definition of union of sets, we have that either $x \in A$ or $x \in B.$ In the first case, we have that $x \in A$ and $x \in C,$ i.e., $x \in A \cap C.$ In the latter, we have that $x \in B$ and $x \in C$, i.e., $x \in B \cap C.$ In both of these cases we reach the conclusion that $x \in (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C),$ just by definition of union of sets. This is enough to show that $$(A \cup B) \cap C \subseteq (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C).$$

On the other hand, consider an arbitrary element $x \in (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C).$ Then, we have that either $x \in A \cap C$ or $x \in B \cap C.$ In the first case, we have $x \in C$ and $x \in A$. Note that since $x \in A$ then it follows that $x \in A \cup B.$ Therefore, it follows that $x \in (A \cup B) \cap C.$ In the latter, we have $x \in C$ and $x \in B.$ Again, note that $x \in B$ implies that $x \in A \cup B$ and therefore we have that $x \in (A \cup B) \cap C.$ With both cases in mind, we've just proved that

$$ (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \cup B) \cap C, $$

proving the equality of sets you're looking for.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this if it's not a problem? - Note that since x∈A
 then it follows that x∈A∪B

Comment: Sure. This conclusion follows directly from the definition of union of sets. We define $$ 
A \cup B = \{ x \, \colon \, x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \}. $$ Therefore, if you know that $x \in A,$ the condition $x \in A \text{ or } x \in B$ is verified, which means that $x \in A \cup B.$

Answer (score 0):

The first inclusion can be shown as follows:

\begin{align}
x \in (A \cup B) \cap C &\rightarrow x \in A \cup B \wedge x \in C\\
&\rightarrow (x \in A \lor x \in B) \wedge x \in C\\
&\rightarrow (x \in A \wedge x \in C) \lor (x \in B \wedge x \in C)\\
&\rightarrow (x \in A \cap C) \lor (x \in B \cap C)\\
&\rightarrow x \in (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C).
\end{align}
Therefore, $(A \cup B) \cap C \subseteq (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$. The other inclusion is proved similarly.